# как объявить переменную и присвоить ей значение

Tags: php, mysql, input

Есть форма c несколькими строками

```
<input type="checkbox" name="rama[<?=$id_rama;?>]" value="<?=$id_rama;?>"/>
```

Переданные из формы значения необходимо вставить в базу данных с полями rama1 = '$rama1', rama2 = '$rama2', rama3 = '$rama3'.

Мой код

```
if (isset($_POST['rama'])) {
$id_pic =  $_POST['id_pic']; // в БД строка с картинкой, к которой подбираются рамки

$rama = $_POST['rama']; // получаем значения инпутов
foreach($rama as $rama_id) { 
'$rama'.$rama_id." = rama".$rama_id.".png;";
}
```

echo $rama{$rama_id} = "rama".$rama_id.".png;"; выдает на странице:

$rama1 = rama1.png;$rama2 = rama2.png;$rama3 = rama3.png;

Но $sql = mysql_query... не видит эти поля, т.е. переменные $rama1, $rama2, $rama3 отсутствуют. Подскажите как их объявить, присвоить им переданные значения?

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = '0';                   // индекс для $rama
for ($n=0; $n<3; $n++) { }

$rama = $_POST['rama'];

foreach($rama as $rama_id) 
{ 

 ${"rama".++$i} = "rama".$rama_id.".png";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach($rama as $rama_id) { 
    ${"rama".$rama_id} = "rama".$rama_id.".png";
}
```

Comment: Этот код - чудовищная дыра в безопасности. Рекомендую открыть для себя массивы

Comment: Где ты увидел дыру в безопасности внутри форыча, умник? Я тут обрабатываю POST? Или может в базу ему эту пишу? Или может ты просто захотел поумничать там, где твое мнение никому не нужно?

Comment: Cпасибо за синтаксис: ${"rama".$rama_id}, с массивами не работаю... Под мою задачку ваш код доработал, т.к.переменная содержит индекс 1,2,3. Если в форме выбираются рамки под номером 7,8,9, то значения не попадают в БД. В БД поля: 
rama1 = '$rama1', 
rama2 = '$rama2', 
rama3 = '$rama3'